# Initializing google map with form values

Tags: javascript, forms, google-maps, button, google-maps-api-3

I have to re-initialize google map from form values. But i am unable to get values of form on click to button (named dynamic_display).Anybody give some idea how to do this.
Map code is:

```
    <script>
        function initialize(a,b,zoom){
 if (!a || !b ||!zoom){ 
//alert('not done '+ "lat="+a+" lang= " +b+" zoom= "+zoom); 
       var centerLoc=new google.maps.LatLng( 53.61701054652337,53.37824736488983);
       zoom=16;
}
else
{
//alert('done' + "lat="+a+" lang= " +b+" zoom= "+zoom);  
var centerLoc=new google.maps.LatLng(a,b);
}
       var mapProp = {
           center:centerLoc,
           zoom:zoom,
           //mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
           mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
       };  
       var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap") ,mapProp);
           marker=new google.maps.Marker({
                  position:centerLoc,
                  title:'Click to zoom'
           });
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'click',function() {
                map.setZoom(map.getZoom()+1);
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
       });
      marker.setMap(map);   
        }
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
```

Form:

```
 <html>
    <body onload="initialize(30,70,5)">
        <form method="GET"  >

                Enter latitude:     <input type ="text" name="lat" id="lat" / ><br/>

                Enter longitude:    <input type ="text" name="lang"  id="lang"/ ><br/>

                Enter Zoom level:   <input type ="text" name="zoom"  id="zoom"/ ><br/>

                                    <input type="button" value ="dynamic_ display" onclick=" initialize(
                                    document.getElementById('lat').value,

                                    document.getElementById('lang').value,

                                    document.getElementById('zoom').value)"/>
                                    <input type="button" onclick=" initialize(32,72,6)" value="Manual_display"/>

                </form>

                                <center><div id="googleMap"  style="width:1000px;height:500px;"></div></center>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is a typo, `<srcipt>`
2. for me the values are accessible inside the function. As you didn't post the function-code, I assume it's a type-error. At least `zoom` is expected to be of type **Number**, but input-values are always of type **String** .
   Use [**Number**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) to convert it into a Number before you use it.

Comment: Thanks i have converted Zoom from string to int and it worked:)